# React doesn't re-render on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am kinda new to react and to the webitself.

this is my render function

```
    render() {
    const {repositories} = this.props

    return (
        <div className='mt4 bt b--black-20 boardingbox scrollarea-content' style={{overflow: 'scroll', height: '100vh'}}>
            {
                repositories.map((repo, index) => {
                    console.log(repo.name)
                    return <Note name={repo.name} desc={repo.name} key={index} onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this) }/>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

The repositories is changing the way I want, but for some reason the its not get re-rendered. I passing the repositiores property from the parent.

The first time I render it (click to the search button, get a response from the server, and set the repo array), its working fine. But at the 2nd search, when there is something in the array, its not working properly, and not re-render.

UPDATE:

The parent's render / onClick

```
render() {
    const {repositories} = this.state
    return (
      <div className='w-third navpanel br b--black-20'>
        <SearchBar onClick={this.onClick} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        <RepoList repositories={repositories}/>
      </div>

      //<NewNote />
      //<Tags />
      //<NoteList />
    );
}

onClick = (event) => {
    const {searchTerm} = this.state

    let endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;
    fetch(endpoint)
        .then(blob => blob.json())
        .then(response => {
            if(response.items)
              this.setState({ repositories: response.items });
        })
}
```

UP-UPDATE:

Search Comp:

```
constructor({onClick, onChange}) {
super()
this.onClick = onClick
this.onChange = onChange
this.state = {
  imageHover: false
}}

render() {
return (
  <div className='flex items-center justify-between bb b--black-20'>
    <div className='ma2 inputContainer w-100'>
      <input className='pa1 pl4 boardingbox w-100 input-reset ba b--black-20 br4 black-50 f6' placeholder='repos' type="text" onChange={this.onChange}/>
    </div>
    <div className='mr2'>
      <div className='boardingbox pointer contain grow'>
        <img src={(this.state.imageHover) ? NoteImageOnHover : NoteImage} alt=''
          onMouseOver={()=>this.setState({imageHover: true})}
          onMouseOut={()=>this.setState({imageHover: false})}
          onClick={this.onClick}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

[first responde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbLy.png)

[second responde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta8iA.png)

Comment: Could you show your parent component?

Comment: You are not specifying the which prop should get assigned to repository. `this.props` is an object. and you're iterating over an object.

Comment: @AmanshuKataria : Nope, OP is using ES6 destructuring to  assign to repositories, notice the `{}` around declaration

Comment: OP: I think your parent component is not setting the "repository" in its state properly. If you use Chrome, try using the [react dev tools plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to see if the state is changing properly or not.

Comment: I aggree with @dubes. Please check your parent component how you are setting your state.

Comment: OP: thanks for the update, before I dig further though, can you please check in your network console that for your 2nd request, the endpoint is being called with the correct search term? Also would be helpful if you can show how you are setting the `searchTerm`

Comment: Thanks guys, to tell you the truth its my first time using stackoverflow, and I am amazed how helpful you guys :).
BTW just updated it.
@dubes

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) I've added an answer which I suspect is the reason for the behavior, let me know if it doesn't work, I will then try to dig in further by reproducing it

Answer (score 0):

The root cause most probably is due to error in function binding.

In your `SearchComponent` you are using the "props" to create function bindings in the *contructor*. This can cause your SearchComponent to refer to wrong instance of the functions for `onClick` and `onChange`. Would suggest referring to the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) for more details.

you do not need to rebind the functions in your `SearchComponent`, you can just use the functions received in `props`.

```
  <input className='pa1 pl4 boardingbox w-100 input-reset ba b--black-20 br4 black-50 f6' placeholder='repos' type="text" onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
  <!-- snipped other irrelevant code -->
    <img src={(this.state.imageHover) ? NoteImageOnHover : NoteImage} alt=''
      onMouseOver={()=>this.setState({imageHover: true})}
      onMouseOut={()=>this.setState({imageHover: false})}
      onClick={this.props.onClick}/>
```

**Why could be happening to cause this behavior**
Remember, constructor is only called once the component instance is being constructed, once it has been created and remains alive, React [lifecycles](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) take over.

So, when you first render your screen, the component is created and since there is only 1 of everything, it kind of works.
When you run your first search: onChange/onClick callbacks modify the state of the parent component. Which then calls `render` on the parent component.

At this point, it is possible that your `SearchComponent` maybe holding on to the wrong instance of the call back methods, which would thus not set state on the parent and thus not force re-render.

**Additional Notes on your constructor**

Normally you shouldn't refer to `props` in your constructor, but if you need to, then you need to have it in the format below. Here are the relevant [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   // other logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and I am really ashamed that I could screw up like this.
So basicly the problem was:

```
return <Note name={repo.name} desc={repo.name} key={index} onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this) }/>
```

So I was as stupid to use INDEX as a KEY so I could not add again the same key to the array.

Thanks anyway guys! :)